# How is "cosmic structure" in cosmology defined?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

**Question**

What qualifies as a "cosmic structure" in cosmology?

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_cosmic_structures .

How is the term defined?  Does the term focus on the mass/energy within the structure or the "shape" of the structure, geometrically?  Is a cosmic structure a geometric region (such as  sphere or some other shape), or the matter or energy within a certain geometric region, or both? Also, is a cosmic structure given by the *presence* of matter/energy, or it's *absence*, or both?  What defines the boundaries of a geometric structure?

**Example**

[For the sake of discussion, assume for a moment that the universe is Euclidean]

For example, given any point $x$ in space and a radius $R$ one can consider the region of space within the distance $R$ of the point $x$.  In other words, a spherical region.  This may be reasonable mathematically, but it may not correspond to a cosmic structure.

Given I pick $x$ to a point near the center of The Milky Way galaxy and choose $R$ to be $52,850$ light years, then I describe a region of space that corresponds to the Milky Way.  But if I pick a different point $x$ and a different radius $R$ I may end up describing a region of empty space in which nothing notable is observed.  Or I may describe a region of space that "belongs" to a larger structure, such as an arbitrary portion of the Milky Way which is not "real" in any other sense than simply being a mathematically well defined collection of points in space.   One could also define other regions, spherical or otherwise, which may end up being completely arbitrary and not "intrinsic".

Comment: There almost certainly isn't a single rigorous definition everybody is using. It's just qualitative features you can pick out. As with all things in reality, the boundaries are fuzzy. For example, there are multiple ways to define where the solar system ends, or where the galaxy ends, or where the observable universe ends.

Comment: The reason that ambiguity is okay in physics (but not as often in mathematics) is that the things we care about are rarely affected by the ambiguities. For example, you could argue for years whether Pluto is _really_, _logically_, _properly_, _rigorously_, _intrinsically_, a planet. But absolutely nothing else would be affected by the call here, the only thing that would change is the planet count. It's irrelevant to discussions about the dynamics of the solar system, or its formation, or its future, etc.

Comment: Is there even a working definition? One thing I am trying to "get at" is the terminology of extremely large cosmic structures and extremely large cosmic distances, on the order of the size of the observable universe.  Where the units of measure are comparable to the radius of the observable universe.  Say, within a factor of 1000 or so.  Where the discussion may become almost theological and philosophical rather than physical because of difficulty of deduction at such a large scale.  Where the difference between the observable universe and the universe itself at large comes in to play. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt there even is a working definition. For example, I clicked on two links in the Wikipedia list at random and found these two papers: [1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.1104.pdf) [2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.08444.pdf#page=9&zoom=100,42,829). They both identify superclusters, but the statistical criteria are completely different! Certainly, you can still argue that a supercluster or void can be identified by a statistically significant deviation, but I doubt there's one measure of deviation used for precisely the reason you said.

Comment: I agree with knzhou, but It is still a useful concept in cosmology for defining physics boundary conditions (i.e for solving with a model). Example : inhomogeneities in the mirowave background radiation, identified with large structures in present universe , that led to the model including inflation.in BB